# Font family overlapping

Tags: php, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to recognize header font of one of website : http://veslio.co
[image] 
Fonts are added into

https://veslio.co/wp-content/themes/veslio/assets/css/style.css

https://veslio.co/wp-content/themes/veslio/style.css

I have created copy of that website here : https://veslio.technocorpus.review
[image]
Fonts are added into
https://veslio.technocorpus.review/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/style.css

Both have same font-family but can not able to determine whats the reason.
Can anyone font family specialist that recornized what is exact issue in https://veslio.technocorpus.review/

Thanks!

Comment: According to my inspector, the font used on https://veslio.technocorpus.review/ is an OTF file and the one on https://veslio.co a WOFF2 file. Does that narrow things down?

Comment: @MrLister thanks for your reply. I appreciate it. I will check it.